# How to count how many zero values when other one column values are not zero by groupby pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For example, I get a `dataframe` as follows:

```
print(df)

    ID    col1    col2
0   0     0       1
1   0     0       0
2   1     1       0
3   1     1       1
4   1     0       1

# after some groupby aggregations
# we calculate that the count of col1 zero values when col2 values are non-zero 
    ID    col1
0   0     2
```

I only know how to count the zero values of a `dataframe` by `groupby` pandas like follows:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())
   ID     col1
0  0      3
1  1      2
```

So I am wondering how to count how many zero values when other one column values are not zero by `groupby` pandas.
I have searched a lot but can't find what I want.
If anyone could help me, it will be great thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but you don't need `groupby` in this case:

```
print( df.loc[(df['col2'] != 0) & (df['col1'] == 0), 'col1'].count() )
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Or:

```
np.sum( (df['col2'] != 0) & (df['col1'] == 0) )
```